# Building a new table by repeating elements from another table

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a small problem that I cannot solve.

I have two tables, one with three elements:

```
a = {0, L/c, 2L/c};
```

and the other with 9 elements, all 0:

```
b = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

I would like to put the elements from table a into table b, giving so that I get the following table:

```
{0, L/c, 2L/c, 0, L/c, 2L/c, 0, L/c, 2L/c}
```

Can someone please give me some advice?

Comment: Do you need `b` at all or do you simply want to generate a list of *n* repeated elements?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if `b` is something important, but if it **is not**:

```
a = {0, L/c, 2 L/c}; 
PadLeft[a, 9, a]
```

> {0, L/c, (2 L)/c, 0, L/c, (2 L)/c, 0, L/c, (2 L)/c}

and if it **is**:

```
b = ConstantArray[0, 9];
PadLeft[a, Length@b, a]
```

> {0, L/c, (2 L)/c, 0, L/c, (2 L)/c, 0, L/c, (2 L)/c}

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {0, L/c, 2 L/c};
b = ConstantArray[0, 9];
Flatten[ConstantArray[a, Length[b]/Length[a]]]
```

Or, even more succinctly:

```
  b = Flatten[ConstantArray[{0, L/c, 2 L/c}, 3]]
```

Comment: Just found out. Thank you very much bill

Comment: @de_wight, if this answer has solved your problem, you should accept it by clicking on the check mark on the left.